# Reading and writing Sinatra params using symbols, e.g. params[:id]

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My form receives data via POST. When I do `puts params` I can see:

```
{"id" => "123", "id2" => "456"}
```

now the commands:

```
puts params['id']    # =>  123
puts params[:id]     # =>  123

params['id'] = '999'
puts params          # => {"id" => "999", "id2" => "456"}
```

but when I do:

```
params[:id] = '888'
puts params
```

I get

```
{"id" => "999", "id2" => "456", :id => "888"}
```

In IRB it works fine:

```
params
# => {"id2"=>"2", "id"=>"1"}

params[:id]
# => nil

params['id']
# => "1"
```

**Why can I read the value using `:id`, but not set the value using that?**

Comment: question is why params[:id] reads value for param id, while assignment :id creates new variable under new name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hashes in Ruby allow arbitrary objects to be used as keys. As strings (e.g. `"id"`) and symbols (e.g. `:id`) are separate types of objects, a hash may have as a key both a string and symbol with the same visual contents without conflict:

```
irb(main):001:0> { :a=>1, "a"=>2 }
#=> {:a=>1, "a"=>2}
```

*This is distinctly different from JavaScript, where the keys for objects are always strings.*

Because web parameters (whether via GET or POST) are always strings, Sinatra has a 'convenience' that allows you to ask for a parameter using a symbol and it will convert it to a string before looking for the associated value. It does this by using a custom default_proc that calls `to_s` when looking for a value that does not exist.

Here's the [current implementation](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/71c1e2aa1855720f41c1e699006439352f97be0f/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1083):

```
def indifferent_hash
  Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }
end
```

However, it does not provide a custom implementation for the `[]=(key, val)` method, and thus you can set a symbol instead of the string.